# Can "an act of protest" and "a sign of protest" be used interchangeably? Are they idioms that are synonymous with each other?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, differences, idioms, synonyms

Can *"an act of protest"* and *"a sign of protest"* be used interchangeably? Are there contexts where one of these phrases should be used, and not the other?

Also, are "*act of protest*" and "*sign of protest*", idioms? Are they synonymous to each other?

Comment: Do *act* and *sign* mean the same? Beyond that, it is of  interest only to writersSE. Voting to close as not a real Q.

Comment: @Kris I would like to know if *"act"* and *"sign"*, when combined with *"of protest"* may have a different meaning compared to when they appear individually. Are *"act of protest"* and *"sign of protest"*, idioms? Are they synonymous to each other? (adding this in the question)

Comment: General Reference. *Act* and *sign* are different words with clearly different meanings, and there's no reason why *"of protest"* should affect things any more than *"of desperation"*, or *"of willpower"*, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. The semantics are straight-forward here. An *act* of protest might be a riot or a march; a *sign* of protest might be a piece of political graffiti on a wall. The one is an act, or action; the other is a signifier or symbol. In many cases either expression may fit, given the context, but the meanings are not the same.